# Difference between module type in tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, angular

In tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

I cannot understand the difference between following `module` types:

> "commonjs", "amd", "umd", "system", "es6", "es2015", "none"

**Question:** Which value should I use and when should I use it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

CommonJS pattern (or nodejs):

```
var someOtherFunction = require('./someOtherFunction.js');
exports.add = function() {
    var sum = 0, i = 0, args = arguments, l = args.length;
    while (i < l) {
        sum += args[i++];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

ES6 pattern:

```
import someOtherFunction from './someOtherFunction.js';

export function add() {
    var sum = 0, i = 0, args = arguments, l = args.length;
    while (i < l) {
        sum += args[i++];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

AMD pattern:

```
define(['someOtherFunction'], function () {
    return function () {
        var sum = 0, i = 0, args = arguments, l = args.length;
        while (i < l) {
            sum += args[i++];
        }
        return sum;
    };
});
```

**Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)** is the most popular for client-side code, while node.js modules (an extension to CommonJS Modules/1.1) is the leading pattern in server-side environments.

**Universal Module Definition (UMD)** is a set of boilerplate recipes that attempt to bridge the differences between AMD and node.js, allowing engineers to author their code bases in a single format, rather than author in both formats or convert to the other format in a build step.

ES5 is the normal JavaScript that you used to see.

You'd be using ES6 for Angular2, also known as ECMAScript 2015.

Comment: using ES6 Is it supported to all old and new browser

Comment: Obviously not , but you're defining target="es5" , which means it will be compiled to es5 which is supported by most of the browsers . So you're fine

Comment: which **module**  type is more flexible or supported to use for any browser

Comment: @kokadwarprafulla, just explained , you'd use ES6 , it would be compiled to Es5 and is supported very well,

Comment: Wouldn't the first example be more suggestive of commonjs if it defines the "add" function and then exports it via `module.exports = { add }` instead?